# RoR put method for adjusting many ListElements into List-model or into ListElement-model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a problem on my Rails project considering which `model` to choose for defining a `method`. I have the following two models

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :list_elements
end

class ListElement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
  #has UNIQUE attribute called 'priority'
end
```

When adding a `ListElement` with `priority = 2`, I need to

```
UPDATE list_elements SET priority = priority+1 WHERE priority >= 2 AND list_id=?
```

in order to free the `priority = 2` slot for the new `ListElement`.

### ---------------------------

Do I put the method achieving this into the `List`-class or into the `ListElement`-class?

So, is the `List` responsible for managing its `ListElements` OR is each model responsible for managing its own table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just do it in a class method on ListElement if this is an isolated task.

If there are more activities to be done, I'd create a separate service class to orchestrate all of them.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Actually, I thought about creating a `before_save`-callback in `ListElement`, which frees the space; and afterwards saves. Can you please elaborate a bit what you mean by "more activities" and where exactly to put a "service class" in case it's needed?

Comment: More activities as in if other models need to be updated from the controller action to create this ListElement. 

A service class is a plain Ruby object which can live anywhere, but i usually put them into app/services to take advantage of Rails autoloading.

Comment: Not a fan of callbacks, since they may need to be untangled if requirements change down the line.

Comment: I see, however, I'm pretty sure the callback will work in my case, since there is no other stuff to be done.